# What does removal of a 3-clique from a graph actually entail?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm pretty new to graph theory, and "removal" of a 3-clique is is a little confsuing to me. I'm comfortable with the definition of a clique, as well as k-cliques. This paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X11002794
defines 3-cliques as cycles in Lemma 1, and cycles have to be defined by vertices and edges (I would think). By "remove" a 3-clique, do you think the author means simply remove edges of the clique? Or remove edges and vertices? If the former, it's easier for me to wrap my mind around the rest of the paper.

I read another question on here where the question-writer referred to clique removal as removing vertices (and their edges, since an edge can't go to a non-existent vertex). That sort of makes sense, but the author of this paper says, also in Lemma 1, that "A cycle in
G is said to be separating if it divides G into two non-empty subgraphs S and S'; that any pair of vertices i is an element of S and j is an element of S' is connected by a path which always includes at least one vertex from the cycle."

So, "one vertex from the cycle" makes me think the author is not removing vertices when removing 3-cliques, but instead removing edges?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't expect "removal of a $3$-clique" to *consistently* mean deleting or not deleting the vertices. In this article, from context, removing the $3$-clique does delete all three vertices of the clique (as well the edges between them and the edges from the clique to the rest of the graph).

To understand statements like the definition of a separating cycle $C$, you have to switch back and forth between the original graph $G$ and the graph $G-C$ with the cycle removed, as appropriate. The same statement, with elaboration:

A cycle $C$ in $G$ is said to be separating if $G-C$ can be divided into two nonempty subgraphs $S$ and $S'$ with the following property: for any two vertices $i \in S$ and $j \in S'$, any $i-j$ path in $G$ always includes at least one vertex from $C$.

In our particular scenario, where $C$ is a $3$-cycle (i.e. a $3$-clique) and $G$ is a *maximal* planar graph, $S$ and $S'$ will be the connected components of $G-C$. If $G-C$ is not connected, then it has two connected components, and we can take those to be $S$ and $S'$. If $G-C$ is connected, then $C$ is not a separating cycle.

That description will not quite hold in general; it is possible for $G-C$ to have more than two connected components, in which case we arbitrarily distribute them between $S$ and $S'$. The paper doesn't really go into detail on that, because it doesn't matter for the specific case it considers.

Comment: Thank you. Looking at the third paragraph of your response, is it saying C exists even if it's been removed? Exists separately, maybe? Because if that's the case, "includes at least one vertex from C" makes sense. If the cycle vanishes into thin air, then I don't see how any path could include at least one vertex from C.

Comment: When we remove the cycle $C$ from the graph $G$, the result is the graph $G-C$. The cycle $C$ does not exist in $G-C$, but it exists in the original graph $G$, and we are only talking about paths in $G$ when we talk about paths that include a vertex from $C$.